# rails' activerecord stores data into wrong table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following model

```
# app/models/admin/furniture/wood/type.rb

class Admin::Furniture::Wood::Type < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

but when I'am trying to save the model, it stores into the wrong table!! only this model is wrong all other models are working ok.

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem, I checked everything `model's path`, even specified the table name with `self.table_name` nothing worked!! Why??

---

#### Edit:

The migration file:

```
# db/migrate/20170505064612_create_admin_furniture_wood_types.rb

class CreateAdminFurnitureWoodTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :admin_furniture_wood_types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :comment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Database config file:

```
# config/database.yml
# MySQL. Versions 5.0 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  variables:
    sql_mode: 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

development:
  <<: *default
  database: viramobl_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: viramobl_test
  password: <%= ENV['TRAVIS'] ? '' : 'root' %>

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: viramobl_production
  username: viramobl
  password: <%= ENV['VIRAMOBL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Can you show us the migration file for the model?

Comment: @Pavan the migration file included.

Comment: Type is a reserved word.

Comment: @pascalbetz I had it somewhere else(under some other namespaces) and I have no problem with that. [`type` is not also a keyword](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/keywords_rdoc.html).

Comment: @dariush no, type is not a ruby keyword. But a reserved word in rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is triggered when a database table has a column named `type` or your model name is ending with `types`. In these cases Rails uses [single table inhertance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) methods and conventions when saving instances.

Just rename that model to something else that makes sense in your domain: `Admin::Furniture::Wood::Kind` or `Admin::Furniture::Wood::Category`

Furthermore, there is a convention in Rails that models are named in singular and their tables are named in plural. Think of it like there is only one class with that name, but the table stores multiple instances of that class.

Whenever you name your classes not following that conventions you have to explicitly tell Rails about that using the [`table_name=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D) method.

Comment: changing the name of the model due to some complications didn't worth the time, I used the `table_name=` and fixed the issue.